# Renaming or naming a filename in python

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-handling

I tried to name the file or rename a file in python, but it is showing a invalid syntax at the end of the path, before ',r'

```
os.rename(r  'D:\\Stackoverflow\\SC.png'  ,r 'D:\\Stackoverflow\\Screen'+str(localtime)+'.png')
```

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python. The answer is, you should probably use regular forward slashes - and then you'll never ever have to deal with this kind of errors again

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I came to know more about the escape sequences in Python. Once again thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime 
import os

src = "/tmp/test.txt"
dst = "/tmp/python_" + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S')) +".inf" 

os.rename(src, dst)
```